# needs assistance in writing cte recursive in py spark azure databricks which is in below sql format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE dates(dt) AS
(
    
    SELECT  to_date('2023-03-05') -181 as dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dt + 1
    FROM dates d
    WHERE d.dt <  to_date('2023-03-05')
)
```

## I have tried with below code under sql frame work its not working in databricks

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE dates(dt) AS
(
    
    SELECT  to_date('2023-03-05') -181 as dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dt + 1
    FROM dates d
    WHERE d.dt <  to_date('2023-03-05')
)
```

Comment: you asked a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76563427/how-to-write-a-cte-recersive-in-pyspark-azure-data-bricks) question some time back. please update/delete that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Spark doesn't support native recursive CTE syntax. You can track the status using the [SPARK-24497](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24497) Jira.

Until it's implemented you will need to use some workarounds, like, described in the [following article](https://medium.com/globant/how-to-implement-recursive-queries-in-spark-3d26f7ed3bc9) - where you can do a combination of normal CTE and unions.